# How to run Python 2.7 Environment In Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

i am trying to run python 2.7 on my Notebook, but the setup code fails:

```
conda create --name python27 python=2.7
```

**error:**

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python=3.7

Current channels:

- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/osx-64
- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/noarch

anyone know how to solve it?

tried this:https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-manage-anaconda-environments/?unapproved=23378&moderation-hash=9d3a3d01f2257771adf184891b3afc0b#comment-23378

and this:https://www.bountysource.com/issues/69268090-removeerror-requests-is-a-dependency-of-conda-and-cannot-be-removed-from-conda-s-operating-environment

Comment: When I try this, it works fine. What OS are you on? And did you already try to reinstall anaconda?

Comment: thank you for your answer, haven't yet, because i am afraid it will mess up my libraries. I am on Mac.

Comment: it is solved. thank you  Psychotechnopath

Comment: What did you do to solve? Reinstall anaconda?

Comment: just before i uninstalled my anaconda, i came across these snippet:
    'python2 -m pip install ipykernel'
    'python2 -m ipykernel install --user'
run them in Terminal, now, i have python 2 in Jupyter to choose from.

Comment: seems no way to follow users here in stackoverflow.